# Spring boot kafka listener not reading messages when initial offset is not given

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am trying to use spring boot kafka consumer (kafka is already setup in a server) but when i try consuming messages from a particular topic it does not read anything unless i specify an initial offset. But when specifying an initial offset whenever the consumer restarts the same messages gets processed again.

When I don't provide an initial offset, it should ideally read from the latest committed offset or from earliest based on the auto-offset-reset config. After the project starts I push some new messages to the topic but spring-kafka does not read the new messages or even the old messages after startup.

This my application.yml

```
server: 
  port: 9000

spring:
   kafka:
     consumer:
        bootstrap-servers: ip
        group-id: test-consumer-group
        auto-offset-reset: earliest
        key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
     producer:
        bootstrap-servers: ip
        key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

This is my listener

```
@Service
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumer {

    // @KafkaListener(groupId = "test-consumer-group", topicPartitions =@TopicPartition(topic = "word-count-output", partitions = "0"))
//  @KafkaListener(groupId="test-consumer-group", topics="word-count-output")

    @KafkaListener(topicPartitions = @TopicPartition(topic = "word-count-output", partitionOffsets = {
            @PartitionOffset(partition = "0", initialOffset = "0") }))
    public void consume(String message) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

If i try any of the commented annotations then the listener does not read any message.

Comment: considering your code you are only reading from partition `0` so have you published messages to partition `0`?

Comment: yes when i specify that i want to read from offset "0" ,it reads the messages from the given topic.But when i don't specify the initial offset it does not read anything

Comment: You can check the status of your consumer group with the `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` CLI - it will show the status of your group (current offset, lag).